# is sleep() accurate enough in python?

Tags: python, time, sleep

I have created a python script that records the up-time of PC throughout the day, and stores the usage in a database the next day.

```
while 1:
        time.sleep(59.9)
        # now some code that increments the up-time value by 1 minute
        # my other code here
```

This is the blueprint of the time adder function which halts the execution for 59.9s (I chose 59.9s instead of 1 minute, as the incremented value needs to be written to 2 separate files, so i wanted to give about 100ms of time in order for the completion of those operations in time) and then writes the incremented value to two separate files, and continues to do so until the system is turned off. 
(every single iteration of this loop will signify that a minute has passed by )

The reason why I went for `sleep()` instead of some other way of elapsing/storing time, is because it counters fairly well in case of power surge's, as the incremented up-time is being written every minute.

I know that the `time.sleep()` function is not a precise and accurate one when it comes to halting time for a subtle duration (in milliseconds or microseconds). But since in my code the time is being halted for approximately a minute, so I believe that the deviation/inaccuracy of the sleep function won't be considerable.

I have tested the above script for about 2 months and the results are quite favourable.

So I was wondering whether it is an efficient way of storing up-time, or there exists a better way of doing so.

Comment: There is an `uptime` command in linux if that is the OS you are using using which you can record uptime!

Comment: Sorry I am on windows :(

Comment: Seems wildly optimistic to assume two writes to disk will always take 100ms, this will dwarf the inaccuracy in sleep. If this gives you "quite favourable" results then obviously your idea of accuracy is different to mine - I would expect this to drift by _minutes_ daily; behaviour which - in any kind of time keeping device - would be unacceptable this side of the invention of the pendulum.

Comment: to get PC uptime you can use `systeminfo` command. I find [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/555737/how-to-find-windows-uptime) with google search `windows uptime`

Comment: any suggestions?

Comment: `that increments the up-time value by 1 minute` - I would do it that way: Do your task, get current time, calculate difference between current time and the time with 1 minute added and rounded to 60 seconds. Then sleep up to that time, ie. (pseudocode) `sleep(((now() + 59) % 60) - now())`. Keep the number of seconds always rounded up to the next whole minute. Sleeping just `59.9` will always give you bad results.

Comment: is there any other method of getting accurate up-time instead of using sleep()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [GetTickCount64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-gettickcount64) function.

**Exmaple:**

```
import ctypes
import datetime


def uptime_in_ms():
    lib = ctypes.windll.kernel32
    return lib.GetTickCount64()

def frmt(dt):
    d = dt.days
    _s = dt.seconds
    h, rem = divmod(_s, 3600)
    m, s = divmod(rem, 60)
    return f'{d} day(s), {h:02}h:{m:02}m:{s:02}s'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ms = uptime_in_ms()
    dt = datetime.timedelta(milliseconds=ms)
    uptime = frmt(dt)
    print(uptime)
```

**Testing:**

```
C:\Users\User>python Desktop/get_uptime.py
1 day(s), 00h:18m:51s
```

**Notes:**

1. Minimum supported client - Windows Vista
2. This is just an example so there is no validation if this library exists
3. This example is using f-string formatting - Python 3.6+

Comment: Thanks.That works. Btw how does getTickCounter64 react when OS is in sleep or hibernating? Does it keep on recording the time or it halts until a proper start, and how accurate is this function when it comes to recording up-time?

Comment: 1. Sorry, I'm not actually a Windows user so you will have to test this yourself. 2 Please refer to MS docs for further details.

Comment: There _must_ be a sane way to format dates in Python!

Comment: @BoristheSpider yes there is, you can just use `str(datetime.timedelta(milliseconds=129600000))`.