# is gettickcount64 accurate for longer time durations?

Tags: windows, winapi, time

After my previous question :- [is sleep() accurate enough in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55914418/is-sleep-accurate-enough-in-python)

The answer stated the use of gettickcount64 for storing up-time since system startup. gettickcount64 lacks precision (due to resolution being approx 10 milliseconds to 16 milliseconds) but still shows high accuracy (compared to querybiaseduninterruptedtime).

I can't understand what's precision and accuracy in this context, so I can't decide whether I should use gettickcount64 to get up-time of my PC or not?

I just want a timer which shows consistent results when used over long duration's (min-hours).

Comment: `GetTickCount64` can be used for any long time period. when say `GetTickCount` restricted to ~49 days

Comment: I know It boasts a long time period, but I wanted to know whether the results that will show up later will be accurate enough or not? Like If I had actually used my system for 10 hours and 5 min, how much difference will exist in the actual result (10 hours and 5 min) vs the result off gettickcount64.

Comment: yes, result will be accurate in the range of 10 milliseconds to 16 milliseconds - no matter what time period you measure

Comment: You can have a look at the official documents，https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-gettickcount64

Comment: documentation is way too cryptic, atleast at my level

Comment: ticks count updated by system timer, resolution limited to the resolution of the system timer, but this *10 milliseconds to 16 milliseconds.* is constant value, not accumulative/ so for any period (no matter 1 second or 10 days you will be have the same *10 milliseconds to 16 milliseconds.*)

Comment: `GetTickCount64` as accurate as the system timer. can not be more, but not less

Comment: so ever after 10 days (or any other time period) the result will be actual time + (10 to 16ms)

Comment: *so ever after 10 days ..* - yes

Comment: Thanks for Taking time to answer my question ^_^